# Docstring doesn't show on hover in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, docstring

When I import a function into a vscode notebook, instead of getting a docstring I just get this:

[image]

Here is the function:

```
def balance_binary_target(df, target="", ratio=None):
    """
    Takes data frame X and target string
    Returns dataframe with upsampled balanced classes
    """
    classes = df[target].value_counts()
    class_differential = classes[0] - classes[1]
    if class_differential < 0:
        class_value = 0
        upsample = np.abs(class_differential)
        if ratio:
            upsample = int(ratio * upsample)
        sample = df[df[target] == class_value].sample(upsample, replace=True)
        df = pd.concat([sample, df])
    elif class_differential > 0:
        class_value = 1
        if ratio:
            upsample = int(ratio * upsample)
        upsample = np.abs(class_differential)
        sample = df[df[target] == class_value].sample(upsample, replace=True)
        df = pd.concat([sample, df])
    return df
```

When I hover over the same function in the simple file text editor I get this:

[image]

How can I get the same detail showing in the jupyter notebook as I do in the base editor?

Here is my version of vscode:

[image]

Here is my version of the Python extension:

[image]

Comment: Can you give the example code? And explain detailed information such as your VSCode version, Python expansion version. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Updated request

Comment: What is your Jupyter file? There is no problem you said here. https://imgur.com/Zq9Uw3a.png

Comment: This is the file location. It is a .ipynb notebook. https://imgur.com/a/g2KV6yu

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean: Where is your `balance_binary_target` defined? Where do you use `balance_binary_target`? Where is the`. py` and `.ipynb` files?

Comment: [This is my test.](https://imgur.com/f225nvz.png)